# issue with fragment: disable pageviewer and load a specified fragment

Tags: android

hi mate i have an activity with pageviewer. every page is a fragment and the user can swype to changepage.
In the action bar there are an action item called "C".
if user click on C, i want to disable pageviewer and load a fragment called "F-C". After clicked on C the user must see only the fragment "F-C" on the screen.
how can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this blog post.  I think he describes in detail the exact functionality you want.

http://blog.svpino.com/2011/08/disabling-pagingswiping-on-android.html

Comment: its more easy if mPager is the viewpager i can use setVisibility no?